# Why isn't my text aligned to the bottom-left of my container?

Tags: html, css

I tried with padding-top and padding-right but the box moves and the text never gets blocked on the corner. Look at the images. I'm doing a basic card. I'm a 1-week beginner.

This is what I'm supposed to do:

[image: This]

This is what it looks like when I do what the video says:

[image: This]

```css
.card {
  height: 300px;
  background: silver;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <h3>Swiss Bank.</h3>
  <p>Digital Card.</p>
</div>
```

If I put more padding-top and right, the box continues opening and opening and is FREAKING frustrating

Comment: "what the video says" What video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue comes from the `height` property that you used.

It's creating the space under the text.
If you get rid of it, the box will only be as big as the content.
In this case: **padding-top** + **height of the text**.

```css
.card {
  background: silver;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  width: 500px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your elements inside `.card` to be on bottom left corner, you should:

Assign `position: relative;` to `.card` and create a div tag inside `.card` where you put your elements (`h3` and `p`)

Assign to the div created

- `position: absoloute;`
- `bottom: 0;`
- `left: 0;`

```css
.card {
    height: 300px;
    background: silver;
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

.corner {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="corner">
    <h3>Swiss Bank.</h3>
    <p>Digital Card.</p>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I like a [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) solution here. It's simpler than absolute positioning in terms of markup and more, er, flexible.

```css
.card {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: silver;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
  padding-right: 30%; /* only needed if you want to limit text width */
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <h3>Swiss Bank.</h3>
  <p>Digital Card.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to add a bit more markup in your html, you can reduce the amount of CSS you use with flexbox (there's a good guide at [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and this [video](https://youtu.be/u044iM9xsWU) from Kevin Powell and also [flexbox froggy](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) game which is kinda fun.

```css
.card {
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
  background: silver;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div><!-- Added this extra container -->
    <h3>Swiss Bank.</h3>
    <p>Digital Card.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```